# swift use of unresolved FbAppCall

Tags: swift, facebook

i am following the firebase tutorial which is **Authenticating Users with Facebook** https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login-objc/blob/master/docs/v1/providers/facebook.md
However, i tried to compile this code and it shows the error of use of unresolved identifier 'FBAppCall'

This code was provided in the tutorial.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

...

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String!, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

    var wasHandled = FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication:sourceApplication)

    // any app-specific handling code here
    return wasHandled
}
```

}

[image: This is the screenshot]

I tried to delete the fb framework and "re-install" it because i thought it related to the fbsdk version. However, it still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think FBAppCall is deprecated use this instead should be fine

```
 return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```